# Display JSON data in separate TextViews

Tags: android, json, textview

i am sending a list with two nodes "message" and "sender" from a webService to an android device via JSON, now i want to separate the sender and message then display them in a TextView

### Webservice

```
[WebMethod]
    public string GetMessage(String receiver)
     {
      try
      {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
        myCommand.Connection = con;
        myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT message, sender FROM [Messages] WHERE receiver = '" + receiver + "'";

        SqlDataReader reader;

        reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        List<string> message = new List<string>();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                message.Add (Convert.ToString(reader["sender"]));
                message.Add  (Convert.ToString(reader["message"]));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return USER_NOT_EXIST_CODE;
        }

        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(message);
       return json.ToString();

    }
```

### MainActivity

```
   protected void onPostExecute(String params) {
        super.onPostExecute(params);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        try {
            Log.v("XXX", params);
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(params);

        message.setText(jsonObj.getString("message"));

            sender.setText(jsonObj.getString("sender"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
```

### Current LogCat

```
     ["0333                ","hi jigZ","0333                ","i am fine","0333                ","hi there"]
```

Comment: what kind of JSON library are you using for android activity? The org.json.JSONObject class does not have a `toString(String)` method

Comment: my bad it was "getString(String)" method

Comment: Ok :) can you please post the raw JSON? Something like `Log.v("TAG", jsonObj.toString(2));` ?

Comment: come on teamwaever...:P

Comment: check this @AdilWaqar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: check this also:   http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things you need to consider...

1) You are accessing **"message"** and **"sender"** form the json, and interistingly, your json doesn't have any keys even similar to them...So first, create a reasonable json...probabaly JsonArray, with JsonObjects having sender and message. That might look like this...

```
[
  {"message":"some text...","sender":"123"},
  {"message":"some text...","sender":"456"},
  {"message":"some text...","sender":"789"}
]
```

This can be easily generated form objects using [NewtonsJson](http://json.codeplex.com/) like this.

```
List<Message> list = new List<Message>();
list.Add(new Message() { sender = "123", message = "some text..." });
list.Add(new Message() { sender = "456", message = "some text..." });
list.Add(new Message() { sender = "789", message = "some text..." });

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Where 'Message' is the simple class holding information...

```
class Message
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string sender { get; set; }
}
```

2) Now Create a similar class in you Android project for 'Message' and you can easily parse this like

```
private List<Message> decodeJson(String fromServer) {
    List<Message> list = new ArrayList<Message>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsAry = new JSONArray(fromServer);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsAry.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsObj = (JSONObject) jsAry.get(i);
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.setSender(jsObj.getString("sender"));
            msg.setMessage(jsObj.getString("message"));
            list.add(msg);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return list;
}
```

And now, you can do any thing you want with this list of Message. You can also add more fields in you class like 'receiver' etc.

Hope this helps...:)